# Should Node.js apps be published to npm?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am making a Node.js server application. It is hosted on GitHub and I thought that I would publish it to npm to make it easier to install for users.

The problem is, when I run npm install my-app, it installs it to the node_modules directory. I would like it to be installed into the current directory, kind of like a git clone would do.

Is this a valid use case for npm publish? Or should I just stick with the git clone, npm install, npm start flow?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are designing a library/plugin, then by convention  it should work in the node_modules folder.

If you are building a standalone application, then stick with the git clone repository.